# Combining data from two columns in the same table into one and getting a count using SQL query

Tags: sql

| Type_1 | Type_2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | b |
| c | a |

I have two columns in the same table similar to above where each row has two types, I am trying to get a count for each type (i.e how many a, b ,c etc) from both columns and a resulting table that has column headers of Type (a,b,c etc) and the COUNT for each one.

The result for this example should look like this:

| Type | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 2 |

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(Type) FROM  (
    SELECT Type_1 AS Type FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Type_2 AS Type FROM table_name
)  x
GROUP BY Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You an unpivot and aggregate.  One method uses `union all`:

```
select type, count(*)
from (select type_1 as type from t union all
      select type_2 from t
     ) t
group by type;
```